# Drupal 8 installation (bash) script. I want the latest stable v8 version each time. But how?

Tags: 8, installation, version-control, installation-profiles

My Drupal 7 script utilised a make file which specified '7.x' as the Drupal version to install, drush make would fetch the correct core files.

My current Drupal 8 script uses git to clone and then checkout a version, eg. 8.1.0, and then renames the remotes as per the instructions on [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/803746). However since this method downloads the entire Drupal project history, I end up with a huge project folder.

I work for an agency and we install Drupal for website projects, so our need is not for the latest dev builds, otherwise I image I would just use:

```
git clone --depth=1 [url to drupal.git]
```

I'm looking for a way to clone the latest stable (release) v8 branch, with no extra files. I could specify the zip on the release page, but this would mean updating the script upon each new release. I tried using Composer, but ended up with a much more complex than necessary folder structure.

Can someone help me with a way to get essentially a copy of the latest v8 .zip file via a script?

Thanks!

Comment: I still use drush make for managing drupal 8 sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mradcliffe said in the comment, if you don't want to use composer (which I would really recommend you look into), you can simply use drush. You just need this:

```
drush dl drupal
```

This defaults to the latest stable Drupal 8 version. If you want to have a git clone (which is way slower), you can tell drush to do that too:

```
drush dl --package-handler=git_drupalorg drupal
```

Comment: drush dl drupal suits my use case perfectly. I found supporting arguments to specify the version (so I can use the same command for Drupal 7), configure the instal dir etc.